# Where is the "Team members" panel in Team Explorer 2012

Tags: templates, tfs, workspace

I installed the team explorer 2012 and the TFS Power Tools 2012 because i need the workspace template functionality. But after starting the Team Explorer and connecting to our TFS 2012 i cannot find the "Team Members" menu where i can set those workspace templates. Am i missing something? Is this menu located elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The team members hub is part of the [power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).

Comment: Yes i know. But though i installed them, i cannot see the team menu.

Comment: I am dumb... i recognized, that i had no members in the teamproject and thus the menu was hidden...

Comment: I can't see it. Does it not work when the project is in TFS 2010?