# Team members panel not displaying in VS2012 with TFS power tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have VS 2012 professional update 4 and the TFS power tools installed. In team explorer i see the usual items (pending changes, work items, builds, reports, documents, web access, settings) but nothing new because of the power tools. We have a number of groups in the team project with active members. How can i view the team members panel in the team explorer ?

I think we are running TFS 2012 but i cannot be certain. How can i check what version of TFS we are running ? I assumed there would be an error if it was 2010

Thank you for any advice

I checked the following links but they did not help me

[Where is the "Team members" panel in Team Explorer 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457621/where-is-the-team-members-panel-in-team-explorer-2012)

[Team members power tools 2012 with TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265584/team-members-power-tools-2012-with-tfs-2010)

Comment: Which version of the power tools did you install?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i installed the Visual Studio 2012 Power Tools for Team Foundation Server version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFS Team Collaboration tools for Visual Studio 2012 and up only work with TFS 2012 and higher (including Visual Studio Online). They do not show when connected to TFS 2010 because the data model changed between 2010 and 2012 and the TFS Team Collaboration tools are not backwards compatible. This means you need to use Visual Studio 2010 unfortunately to access the Team options, or upgrade TFS 2010 to 2012 or higher.

You need to install the version that matches your Visual Studio version. If you're using 2010 and 2012 you need to install them side by side (you can do this by unchecking the Powershell and Explorer Integration in the older versions and leaving these enabled in the most recent versions of the Power Tools.

- [Visual Studio 2010 Power Tools for Team Foundation Server](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)
- [Visual Studio 2012 Power Tools for Team Foundation Server](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)
- [Visual Studio 2013 Power Tools for Team Foundation Server](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

In Visual Studio, make sure you have the TFS Team Collaboration tools listed and is enabled in the "Extensions and Updates" screen. If it's not, try removing and re-installing the Power Tools:

[image: Extensions and Updates listing TFS Team Collaboration Extension]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can see Team Foundation Server Power Tools 2012 in extensions and updates. TFS team collaboration is there too. I uninstalled power tools,restarted VS and re installed. (didnt restart machine or log out). I still just see the usual items in the team explorer.

Comment: I did some additional research and it turns our that the Team Members section in VS2012 is not compatible with TFS 2010 due to changes in the data model.

Comment: Thank for you for the effort @jessehouwing